# How to create index on long data type field

Tags: mysql, index, exception

I have a MySQL table with a long data type field:

```
`create_date` long NOT NULL,
```

I want to index it:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_logs_create_date ON `logs` (create_date) USING BTREE;
```

But I encounter the following exception:

```
Error Code: 1170. BLOB/TEXT column 'create_date' used in key specification without a key length 0.049 sec
```

Is it possible to index a long data type field?  I have searched but cannot find anything discussing this particular issue

Comment: Seems you mixed long from C/C++ (as big integer type) with mysql alias 'long' which means mediumtext (string/blob datatype) as can be seen here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57834/1 so you either need to change it to numeric type to save timestamps or to date/datetime which I would prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For long (mediumtext) you have to specify how much of the string you want to index. If you want the first 100 bytes in the column to be indexed:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_logs_create_date ON logs (create_date(100)) USING BTREE;
```

May I ask why you named a column of type long create_date?

Comment: I store dates as longs.  I think I want to convert to bigint

Comment: Well, a mediumtext can store up to 16,777,215 (2^24−1) bytes, are you worried that your date representation may one day require a lot more storage? Don't aim for BIGINT, the only sane thing to do is to store dates as DATE. Assume the following scenario, you want to find out the top five days each month that creates the most log-entries. Using a DATE column it will be a walk in the park, using a BIGINT, well I'll leave that as an exercise for you.